# String substitution: If empty replace, otherwise make empty

Tags: shell, posix

I was wondering if there's a shorthand for this kind of stuff.

Currently I can do.

```
var_empty=; [ -n "$var" ] || var_empty=1; #intermediary variable
echo "REPL_if_var_empty_otherwise_empty=${var_empty:+REPL}"
```

Is this doable without the intermediary?

I tried

```
sh -c 'readonly SAME=SAME; var=; echo test0=${var:-SAME} test1=${SAME:+REPL}; echo REPL_if_var_empty_otherwise_empty=${${var:-SAME}:+REPL}'
```

but this results in a `bad substitution` error in the last `echo` (`test0=SAME test1=REPL`). Why is that? Is there another way?

Comment: If I understand it correctly you want `var_empty=; [[ -n $var_empty ]] || var_empty="${var_empty:=REPLY}"`.  In your case  "${var_empty:+REPL}"  nothing is set if  `var_empty` is null or unset. Maybe this will help you more https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you're after, but what about: `test "$var" && var= || var=was_empty`. There isn't any `${foo?bar:baz}` shortcut.

Comment: @mosvy I'll accept that as an answer. I perversely love asking "is-there-a" questions, but perhaps a no in an answer will help future wonderers. Anyway, I think the fact that my attempt failed is kind of interesting as far as the shell grammar is concerned.

Comment: With `zsh`, you could do `${${var:-empty$var}%$var}`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Nice to know! zsh is doing it right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In bash, ksh or `zsh` in `ksh` emulation, you could do:

```
r=empty;output=${r[${#var}]}
```

In `zsh`:

```
output=${${var:-empty$var}%$var}
```

Otherwise, you can always do

```
output=;[ "$var" ]||output=empty
```

Comment: You need a `unset r` for the first option. Otherwise a previous defined `r` like: `r=(1 2 3)` will still be used. Or, shorter: `r=(empty)`.

Comment: Yes, though arrays are not inherited from the environment, so it's just a matter of using a variable that is not otherwise used earlier in the script. Not sure it's worth mentioning . `r=(empty)` wouldn't work with ksh88.  While we're at nitpicking, in `bash` or `mksh`, `unset` wouldn't work either in some contexts as it doesn't unset but peels off a layer of local scope. In `bash`, you also need `unset -v r` as otherwise it may unset a `r` function. The answer also assumes the `nounset` option has not been set.

Comment: Who is still using ksh88? But the local scope is what gets used down the line, isn't it? True, better to use `unset -v r`. The `nounset` will not be a problem if `var` has been set before, but yes, that is a point. Which may be solved with `var=${var-}`, that will change var only if unset, but will remain `empty`. Or some other workaround.

Comment: @isaac, ksh88 is still the default ksh on some commercial Unices (and often the best shell you get there by defaul). `r=(1 2); f() { local r=x; g; }; g() { unset r; echo "${r[1]}"; }; f` outputs `2` in bash, mksh (and yash, except you need `typeset` and array indices start at 1). The problem with `nounset` is with `${r[${#var}]}`, we rely on it being unset for values of `${#var}` other than 0 so it expands to the empty string.

Comment: Please make it 'g(){ local r; ……' There is no need to unset a var from the upstream scope (without local). And yes, I understand the reason (and problem) with nounset and `${#var}`, but thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I follow what you mean by "without the intermediary" - if you mean "do it all on one line" or "don't even make variable assignments, do it all directly", but here are methods for each interpretation:

Method 1a - With variable assignments:

```
$ testVar=; [[ "${testVar}" ]] && testVar="" || testVar="was empty"; echo $testVar
```

Method 1b - With variable assignments:

```
testVar=; testVar=$( [ $testVar ] || echo "was empty"); echo $testVar
```

Method 2 - No assignments:

```
$ testVar=; [[ "${testVar}" ]] && echo "" || echo "was empty"
```

Output:

```
was empty
```

---

Bonuses:

Generalization - Pick the pieces you need - no variables required at all:

```
echo testValue | { echo -n "Original value: "; tee >(read -n 1 && echo "wasn't empty" || echo "was empty"); }
```

Replace `echo testValue` with the raw command you would be using to assign your variable.

Generalization - using awk:

```
echo -n | awk 'BEGIN{print "Original value: "}; d=1; END{if (!d) {print "was empty"} else {print "was not empty"} }'
```

Again, pick and choose the cases you need (for the OP's question, the original value isn't needed, but that's probably a less-common use-case).  If you need to start from a variable, `echo` it.  If you need to assign the result to a variable, use command substitution (wrap the whole thing in `$( ... )`.

Note: To my knowledge, `sed` won't be of any help in these cases, because it is 100% line-oriented, and the "empty case" is zero-lines by-definition.  Therefore, `sed` will exit before it has a chance to process anything you tell it to.  Also, I'm not very familiar with Perl, but I couldn't figure it out -- though I'm guessing somebody good with Perl could.  Bash's features like `{var:=param}` et al. aren't particularly helpful for the OP's case, but I'll mention them for completeness.  I wish they operated on raw strings instead of just named string variables, for the same reason as the OP (I like to avoid intermediates if I don't need them later).